# MoveTo working on Local instance, authentication error in Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, active-directory, ldap

I've written a small function that enables a user to be moved from one Active Directory OU to another. The starting OU is called **Automation** and the target is **Disabled Accounts**. The Active Directory instance is served on-premise:

```
public function MoveUserToDisabled() 
{
    try
        {

            DirectoryEntry dirEntry1 = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://CN=Auto A AA. User,OU=Automation,DC=orig,DC=global,DC=dev", AdminUsername, AdminPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
            DirectoryEntry dirEntry2 = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://OU=Disabled Accounts,DC=orig,DC=global,DC=dev", AdminUsername, AdminPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

            string newName = dirEntry1.Name;

            dirEntry1.MoveTo(dirEntry2, newName);
            dirEntry1.Close();
            dirEntry2.Close();
            return true;
        }
    catch (InvalidOperationException inOp)
        {
            return "Error(1): " + inOp.ToString();
        }

    catch (COMException comEx)
        {
            return "Error(2): " + comEx.ToString();
        }
    catch (Exception err)
        {
            return "Error(3): " + err.ToString();
        }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "Error(4): " + e;
        }
    
}
```

When running on my local machine, the code executes flawlessly and the user is moved without any issues at all. When running the same code from an Azure Premium Tier function I get the following error:

```
Error(2): System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070005): Access is denied.
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_Name()
at JLM.ADMethodsAccountManagement.MoveUserToDisabled(String sUserName) in function.cs:line 14"
```

Again, the Azure Function is running on a premium tier and has other methods such as disabling a user, modifying a users' attributes and more. These all execute with the same credentials without any issues.

The account **AdminUsername** is part of the Security groups **Domain Admins** and I can perform the above task using Active Directory Explorer with the same AdminUsername & AdminPassword credentials, i.e. dragging the user from the Automation OU to the Disabled Accounts OU.

This seems to be potentially an issue with LDAP in Azure Functions. Would anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I've just resolved the error for our implementation that had exactly the same issue.

We needed to include the name of the active directory instance in the LDAP path for the directory entry.

So, where you have

```csharp
DirectoryEntry dirEntry1 = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://CN=Auto A AA. User,OU=Automation,DC=orig,DC=global,DC=dev", AdminUsername, AdminPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
DirectoryEntry dirEntry2 = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://OU=Disabled Accounts,DC=orig,DC=global,DC=dev", AdminUsername, AdminPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

You need to add the name of the server at the beginning e.g.

```csharp
"LDAP://fully.qualified.server.domain.name/OU=Disabled Accounts,DC=orig,DC=global,DC=dev"
```

Or at least, that's what we needed to do to solve the issue.